# Get index of element in U-SQL SqlArray?

Tags: c#, arrays, ienumerable, u-sql

I'd like to be able to get the first index where a certain element appears in my SqlArray. Something like IndexOf(myArray, "word") would return 0 if the first element in myArray is "word".

Is there a way to do this? I've searched the documentation numerous times and what I understand is that SqlArray probably(?) implements IEnumerable under the hood, although there isn't any IndexOf function under IEnumerable either.

In case it matters, the way I've initialized my array is:

```
DECLARE CONST @namesStr = "a,b,c,d";
DECLARE CONST @names = new SqlArray<string>( @namesStr.Split(',') );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to do this using Scala and Databricks, then you can just use `indexOf`, eg

```
val namesStr = "banana,apple,apricot"

// To array
val a = namesStr.split(",")

a.indexOf("apple")
```

My results:

[image: My results]

If you do need to do this in U-SQL, then there is the `IndexOf` function you could use in a code-behind file, eg something like this:

```
using Microsoft.Analytics.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Analytics.Types.Sql;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace USQLworking2
{
    public class myFunctions
    {
        public static int someFunction(SqlArray<string> someString, string searchString)
        {
            //!!TODO add error / exception handling

            String[] stringArray = someString.ToArray();

            return Array.IndexOf(stringArray, searchString);

        }
    }
}
```

And the U-SQL:

```
DECLARE @outputFile string = @"\output\output.csv";

DECLARE CONST @namesStr = "banana,apple,apricot";
DECLARE CONST @names = new SqlArray<string>( @namesStr.Split(',') );

@output =
    SELECT
        USQLworking2.myFunctions.someFunction ( @names, "apricot" ) AS shouldBe1
    FROM ( VALUES ( 0 ) ) AS x(y);


OUTPUT @output
TO @outputFile
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Comment: I'm using USQL so Scala isn't an option for me here. The USQL code you have provided appears to be retrieving the index of "b" from the string namesStr, which is not the same as retrieving it from an array. For example, if namesStr was "banana,apple,apricot" and I was searching for "apple", I would want the result 1. As in, if we turned it into the list ["banana","apple","apricot"] it's in index 1. I would not want 7, as in the word "apple" starts on index 7 of the string "banana,apple,apricot".

Comment: Great, thanks for the new information.  I've updated the Databricks and U-SQL options.

Comment: Hi @Alex, how are you getting on with tihs?  After your further explanation, does my revised answer, answer your question?  If so, please consider upvoting the question and/or marking it as the answer.

Comment: Hi @wBob, I appreciate your answer but unfortunately by putting it into an external file makes it no longer const-foldable, which is important for my purposes. I've marked your answer as a solution because I did not include this requirement in my original question and because I believe it is not possible to do this in a const-foldable way. Thank you.